# Hackerrank problem: No idea -> Set vs List RUNTIME in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/no-idea/problem

In the above problem, I had a solution like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n, m = map(int, input().split())
    array = list(map(int, input().split()))
    A = list(map(int, input().split()))
    B = list(map(int, input().split()))
    print(sum([(i in A) - (i in B) for i in array]))
```

It turned out Time out in some test cases.
However, if I switched the type of A and B into set, e.g:

```
A = set(map(int, input().split()))
B = set(map(int, input().split()))
```

It perfectly passed all the test cases.
I don't understand why Python 3 runs faster when using set than using list in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set` is a hash-table and `O(1)` lookup, so the operation `(i in A)` is very cheap. When you use `set`, the `sum` is an `O(N)` operation.

`list` is a sequence, so has `O(N)` lookup, so the operation `(i in A)` suddenly becomes very expensive. When you use `set`, the `sum` is an `O(M * N)` operation. For `M ~ N`, that's `O(N^2)`.